# Inserting node at tail

Tags: c, linked-list

The code below is adding a new node to the head of the list. I was wondering how I would change it so that it would add a new node to the tail(end) of the list instead of the head.

```
typedef struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
} Node, *NodePtr;

typedef struct linkedlist{
NodePtr head;
NodePtr tail;
} LinkedList, *LinkedListPtr;

void insertTail(LinkedListPtr list, int data){
NodePtr newNode;
newNode = (NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(Node));

newNode->data = data;
newNode->next =NULL;
newNode->prev =NULL;


/* add it to the beginning of linked list*/
if  (list->head==NULL){ /*linked list is empty*/
    list->head=newNode;
    list->tail=newNode;
}
else {
    //connect new node to the head of the list
    newNode->next = list->head;
    list->head->prev=newNode;

    //reassign head of the list
    list->head = newNode; 
}
}
```

Comment: Your list is doubly linked *and* holds a pointer to the last node, it should be trivial. Just do the reverse of what inserting at the head does.

Comment: You already have a pointer `list->tail`. I would suggest to draw a picture to show yourself which pointers have to be set to what (like: what should list->tail, newnode->prev, newnode->next ... point to) and then try.